# how to merge staging content to live in magento

Tags: magento, merge, staging

I'm setting up a new magento store and have created a copy of my store on subdomain stage.mystore.com.

I want to setup new skus, cms pages/static blocks, promotions etc all on stage so I can test them before moving them to my live store.

My question is, what is the easiest way to push my changes from stage to live? Is there a nice way of doing this without bothering to setup a SVN? I'm comfortable using my SSH client to copy things across, but what's the standard approach for a low budget site to have basic staging environment with Magento?

How can I most easily / safely sync my db between the two? Can I dump certain rows and import them to live? I'm fine to merge the /skin/ files manually, those are super easy to keep track of, but what about custom layout updates and changes to descriptions for catgories, etc? Should I just export part of my db and then import to live? If so, which tables, etc?

Edit to add:

just found this from another question here:

"You can get the CMS (pages and static blocks) data out of the database by dumping and loading just the cms_* tables from whatever environment development was done on."

This sounds like exactly what I need, but I'm a newb at db commands, what would be my command to dumb just these tables? I use this for a complete dump:

mysqldump -u PRODUCTION_DBUSER -p PRODUCTION_DBNAME > data.sql

how do I adjust this to grab just the CMS tables?

Answer (score 0):

you should really consider use [GIT.](http://git-scm.com/) Also, if you can't be bother setting up a server, you can still use [Github.](http://github.com/)  And [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) you can find more information how to create a good workflow for your environments.

Comment: any this is going to help him sync his database and products how? good advice but not what he is asking.